# Insert into an empty table with or without clustered primary key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I will need to insert some rows in an empty temp table. The table has PK of (month date, id char(10)). The source table is partitioned by `month`. Which of the following is faster?

**1a) the target table has clustered PK pre-created.**

```
create table #t (month date not null, id char(10) not null, ...... primary key (month, id))
  with (data_compression = page)
insert into #t select .... from t -- partitioned by month, maybe millions of rows
where ......
```

**1b) Same as (1a). But the insert will try to sort the data first.**

```
create table #t (month date not null, id char(10) not null, ...... primary key (month, id))
  with (data_compression = page)
insert into #t select .... from t -- partitioned by month, maybe millions of rows
where ......
order by month, id
```

**2) Insert into a heap, then add a clustered PK**

```
create table #t (month date not null, id char(10) not null, ...... )
  with (data_compression = page) -- should or should not?
insert into #t select .... from t -- partitioned by month, maybe millions of rows
where ......
alter table #t add primary key (month, id) with (data_compression = page)
```

Will (2) recreate the table `#t` internally?

Comment: Why the question was down voted and three close requests? Isn't it a typical DBA task? Or the developer's code DBA may need to improve?

Comment: Typically, the downvotes and VtC's happen from you not providing enough detail.  I happen to think this question is a good question, it could just use some more details, and it *would* be nice to know what you have experienced, or what you are having trouble with, etc.  I have not downvoted, or VtC'd by the way.  In fact, I voted to leave it open.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server under the covers always does row by row processing. That means if you insert a bunch of rows into a table with a clustered index, each row gets inserted at the (up to then) correct position. That algorithm is called insertion sort and has an average complexity of O(n^2).

If you insert all rows into a heap and then add the index, SQL Server can make use of any of the much more efficient sorting algorithms available.

However, SQL Server often decides, if the conditions allow, to presort the incoming data. In that case the insertion sort (not really a sort at this point) has a complexity of O(n) which cannot be topped by another sorting algorithm. This complexity stays stable even if there is preexisting data in the CI.

That presorting has all the data available (the sort operator is a blocking operator, meaning it first reads all input rows and then does its processing) so a more effective algorithm can be chosen.

So far both methods seem to be on par performance wise.

However, in my experience, a sort to create an index is often a lot faster in SQL Server than a sort to retrieve or copy rows. The reason is that SQL Server uses additional optimization tricks when creating an index that it cannot use in a normal query.

So back to your question, depending on the data, particularly its width and its cardinality, and also dependent on the existence of preexisting data, dropping the index before the insert and re-adding it afterwards might actually be faster, even more so if you have multiple indexes.

But, as always, it all depends on your particular situation, so you have to test for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the primary key after you insert data is a non-starter.  This would necessitate recreating the entire table, since the clustered index (primary key) *is* the table.  The effect here would be negligible if the row count is small, however if the row count is large, this will substantially slow the overall operation, not to mention create totally unnecessary I/O.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought. However, I keep reading people suggestion drop all the indexes, included the cluster indexes before insert into a new table.

Comment: They have never tried it both ways, and timed it.  Otherwise they would know.

Comment: Now, if the object is to get the table running (without indexes) as fast as possible, then *perhaps* I'd delete the non-clustered indexes first, since they can be added later if you have Enterprise Edition with `WITH (ONLINE=ON)`.  I would never dream of deleting the clustered index.